# Reproducing kernel for $L_p$ Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

For a given space $\mathcal{X}$, consider the Banach space $L_p(\mathcal{X},\mu)$ for Lebesgue distribution $\mu$, where $p \neq 2$. It is straightforward that the dual space to this is $L_q(\mathcal{X},\mu)$ where $1/p + 1/q = 1$.

I'm trying to find kernels $\mathcal{K}: \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X} \to C$ and $G: \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X} \to C$ such that

1. $G(x,\cdot) \in L_p(\mathcal{X},\mu)$ and $\mathcal{K}(\cdot, x) = (G(x,\cdot))^*$ for all $x \in \mathcal{X}$
2. $f(x) = (f, G(x, \cdot))_{L_p}$, $f^∗(x) = (K(x, ·), f
   )_{L_p}$, $f \in L_p, f^∗ \in L_p, x \in \mathcal{X}$.

One can consider a semi-inner product in this case where $(f,g)_{L_p} = \frac{\int_{\mathcal{X}} f\bar{g}|g|^{p-2}}{||g||^{p-2}_{L_p}}$ for $f,g \in L_p$. It is clear that the dual map in this case has the following form: $f^* = \frac{\bar{f}|f|^{p-2}}{||f||^{p-2}_{L_p}}$. But it is not clear to me what could be valid reproducing kernels. Can anyone help understand this or provide some idea as to how to construct one?

Comment: What makes you think there is a reproducing kernel? Formally, such a kernel would be given by $K(x,y)=\delta(x-y)$, but this does not fit in your requirements.

Comment: $L_p$, in this case, is a reflexive Banach space, i.e. its dual is isometric to the Banach space $L_q$ and point evaluations are continuous linear functionals on both $L_p$ and $L_q$. One can show the existence of a reproducing kernel for these reflexive Banach spaces, e.g consider Theorem 2 in https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume10/zhang09b/zhang09b.pdf .

Comment: In general there is no such kernel, since point evaluations are not continuous on $L^p$ in general.

Comment: @supernova: my first comment about the Dirac delta has exactly the same content as what PhoemueX says, only stated with a different language. Ultimately, what I am saying above is precisely that point evaluations are typically NOT continuous on L^p.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that in general, this might not hold, but for measure space $(\mathcal{X},\mu)$, one can show that the point evaluations are continuous on $L_p$, right?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I have edited the problem a bit. Do you think one can find such kernels in this case?

Comment: You can almost never find a reproducing kernel. You have one in the trivial case of $\mathcal{X}$ being a finite set, in which case $L^p$ trivializes to $(\mathbb R^n, \lvert\cdot\rvert_p)$ (here, $\lvert x\rvert_p:=(\lvert x_1\rvert^p+\ldots+\lvert x_n\rvert^p)^{1/p}$). I guess you also have one for $\mathcal{X}=\mathbb N$, so that $L^p$ reduces to $\ell^p$. Otherwise, there is a fundamental and insurmountable obstruction: an element $f\in L^p$ is **not** a function, it is an **equivalence class** of functions, defined up to almost everywhere equivalence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PRELIMINARY REMARK**. In the following, $p\in [1, \infty)$. The extreme case $p=\infty$ is not covered by the question, as the duality pairing $(\cdot, \cdot)_p$ defined there makes no sense in that case.

---

Let us consider the case $\mathcal{X}=\mathbb R$. Aiming for a contradiction, suppose that a function $G$ satisfying point 1 existed. Note that, by Hölder's inequality, for arbitrary $f, g\in L^p$ we have that
$$
\lvert (f, g)_{L^p}\rvert\le \lVert f\rVert_p \lVert g \rVert_p, $$
so applying this with $g=G(x, \cdot)$ we obtain that, for each $x\in\mathbb R$, there is $C(x)>0$ such that
$$\tag{1}
\lvert f(x)\rvert\le C(x) \lVert f\rVert_{L^p(\mathbb R)}.$$
Indeed, $C(x)$ can be taken to be $\lVert G(x, \cdot)\rVert_p$.

This inequality (1) is clearly absurd, since $f$ is only defined up to almost everywhere equivalence, hence $f(x)$ can take any value without altering $\lVert f\rVert_{L^p(\mathbb R)}$.

Even if we insisted on trying to prove (1) for continuous $f$ only, we would find it cannot hold unless $p=\infty$. The scaling is off: indeed, considering
$$
f_\lambda(y):=\lambda^\frac{1}{p}f(\lambda(y-x)+x), \quad \text{for }\lambda>0, $$
we have that $\lVert f_\lambda\rVert_{L^p(\mathbb R)}=\lVert f\rVert_{L^p(\mathbb R)}$, while $\lvert f_\lambda(x)\rvert =\lambda^\frac1p\lvert f(x)\rvert$. So the left-hand side of (1) can be scaled to be arbitrarily big, while the right-hand side remains constant. This proves that (1) is absurd, even for continuous $f$ only.

NOTE TO THE READER: This scaling argument is easier to understand in the case $x=0$.

Comment: Why is $C(x)$ constant everywhere? If you fix $f$, $C(x)$ can take any value, right? So, it is not clear to me how (1) becomes a valid premise for your argument. Also, as you pointed out, $L_p$ is can't be a Banach space in the usual sense under Lebesgue measure. But upto the equivalence one can study it as a Banach space, right.

Comment: I added the computation of $C(x)$

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is pretty good. Then, would it make sense to consider the family of functions $\mathcal{F} \subset L_p$ that are pointwise bounded?

Comment: What does "pointwise bounded" mean? (Answer: nothing, whatever you mean the techniques in the present answer would prove it is nonsense)

Comment: Functions $f \in \mathcal{F}$ that are almost everywhere bounded, say by 1. But this would trivialize the problem in the sense that $||f||_{L_p}$ has to be 1 in order to bypass the argument above.

Comment: You mean the space $L^\infty$. You are asking whether $L^\infty$ has a reproducing kernel. I am sure that the answer is negative, but this is not addressed by my answer as it is right now. In any case it is clear that something very wrong is going on, as the dual of $L^\infty$ is not $L^1$ and $L^\infty$ is not reflexive.

Comment: I'm trying to come up with an example of an RKBS on function spaces where you can find an explicit dual map and a kernel. I'm wondering if one can think of a subset of $L_p$ and get an RKBS with a dual map and a kernel. Usually, I find examples of RKBS where either only the kernel is known or only the dual map is known, but not both.

Comment: I bet you can do a $L^p$ version of the [Bergman kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bergman_kernel).

Comment: I tried looking at this. It is defined for holomorphic functions in $L_2$. I'm wondering how you can extend this to $p > 2$. I think you can just consider the holomorphic functions $H_p \subset L_p$, right? I guess, given that $L_p \subset L_2$ we get $H_p \subset H_2$. But the semi-inner product is different in this case so we definitely can't use the same Bergman kernel. This seemed like an interesting paper: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-56/issue-1/The-Bergman-projection-in-Lp-for-domains-with-minimal-smoothness/10.1215/ijm/1380287464.full

Comment: This really deserves another question. I am sure somebody will hop on it, here we have experts in complex analysis who will hopefully take the bait, and we will all end up learning something.

Comment: Yeah I’ll pose this question with the broader community. Nonetheless, it has been really nice discussing this here with you!